# Move the file list to an alternate location in the DOM (fine-Uploader)

Tags: fine-uploader

I need help with this.

I am using fineUploader 4.2.1 and trying to relocate file list to an alternate location in the DOM (our own element on the html page). Here is the code snippet that I have to achieve this.

-- Where I want file list created (manual upload with edit names)

```
<div class="qq-upload-list-container">
    <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

-- My Current Template

```
    < script type="text/template" id="qq-template" >
<div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button qq-btn qq-btn-primary">
            <span>Select Images (Max. 5)</span>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                <a class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
                <a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</ script >
```

-- My JavaScript Code Block.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var manualuploader = $('#image-selector-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        listElement: "qq-upload-list-container",
      //template: "qq-simple-thumbnails-template",
      //template: "qq-template-manual-noedit",
      template: "qq-template",
      thumbnails: {
          placeholders: {
            waitingPath: $webroot + "img/waiting-generic.png",
            notAvailablePath: $webroot + "img/not_available-generic.png"
          }
      },
      request: {
        endpoint: $uploadURL
      },
      validation: {
          allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
      },
      editFilename: {
        enabled: true
      },
      autoUpload: false
    });

$('#upload-trigger-fine-uploader').click(function() {
  manualuploader.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
});
});
```

I am not sure what/where I am getting it wrong but the fineUploader is not creating file list under the DOM "qq-upload-list-container"

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

-BC

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a couple errors in this section of the documentation.  The expected type of your `listElement` option should be an `HTMLElement`, not a String.  Since you are using the jQuery plug-in wrapper, a jQuery object is also an acceptable value type.

So, your `listElement` option value should be `$(".qq-upload-list-container");`

I'll fix the issues with the documentation now.

Comment: I tried this but still no luck. I am not sure where I am coding wrong. Does my listElement DOM section look right? My understanding is that once I specify listElement (just an empty DIV section), fineUploader takes "qq-upload-drop-area-selector", "qq-drop-processing-selector" and "qq-upload-list-container" sections of the template and attaches to listElement specified. Correct?

Comment: Fine Uploader will only relocate the list container element under your listElement.

Comment: If you are still having issues, please share a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue and share the link.

Comment: It worked finally. I was looking for <ul> tag to be loaded right off the bat. However, it's adding <li> tags to my DOM element upon selection of some images. Thanks for your input. Hey, I didn't know anything about jsfiddle but looks like a fantastic way to show & tell the "story". After I saw comment, I tried but I could not get it to work even with basic DEMO code from fineUploader site. Would you be able to share a working fineUploader link @jsfiddle that I can use a reference/copy in case I need to ask additional questions using this?